# Using String as Variable Name (C++)

Tags: c++, settings

Assume I have Variable called "Volume", for example. I now have a file with Settings in it. Every Settings looks like this: ": 
I now go through this file from top to bottom, and I want the program to store the Setting in a Variable with an equal Name.

e.G. if there is "Volume: 76", I want the program to write "76" into the Variable "Volume". How can I make the program to get the right Variable just by the string? Is this even possible?

There is no code yet, since I haven't started working on it yet. I was making thoughts about it.

Comment: In C++, variable names are symbols for the compiler, not actual strings

Comment: Parse, parse, and parse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use variables directly, since the name must be existent at compile time, but reading a file is runtime.

You can use std::map though. Each settings will be a key, and the value will be read in.

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> settings;
settings["volume"] = "76";
```

But, the values ("76" in this case) will be strings as well. You can not use differing types directly.
I think, its possible with type erasure, but thats really advanced (and iam not fluent with it!).

Comment: Since I'd Store the Setting as a number, I could use "Std::map<std::string, int>" I guess

Comment: yes of course. All thats necessary is, that the value has one type, and all settings have them.
You can use a baseclass, where every valuetype is derived, and save a polymorphic pointer to it (unique_ptr). But if you only need numbers, that would work as well.

Comment: I don't know why a Setting should not be a number. If you had to choose between Windows, Fullscreen you could use as well the numbers 0 and 1 (or 1 and 2)

Comment: It alright. Didnt want to implie that, only if you needed something more general.

std::map<std::string, int> settings; is perfectly fine. If its a binary decision, consider bool with an expressive name. (or a functions converting the integer value to the sensefull variable, sanitizing the input!)